# Could getting fired from a second job significant affect the likelihood of admission to a master's program?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters

I am applying to graduate school to work on a Master's of Science in Nursing (Family Nurse Practitioner) in the fall. I've been working for the past few years, and it's time to go back. When I first started applying, I worked two jobs, and my second job is for a company that I'd largely stopped working for (I set my schedule with this company), but I had previously worked with as my primary employer for many years (too big to leave off a resume). Long story short, I was fired from that job about two weeks ago. My primary employment, where I work a regular schedule, is unaffected, and all of references for my application are from my current employer.

The question is: how much is that likely to affect a school's decision on my admission? I understand that there are different departments, different factors, etc., but is it likely that being fired from a second job around the time that applications are due will significantly hurt my chances of getting in?

Comment: I am unclear how a grad school would know you were fired.

Comment: This is something that I'm unclear about as well, and I should have clarified that component of the question: do graduate schools call employers listed on resumes/applications to verify employment? Could they even become aware of that kind of thing?

Comment: Was your job related to nursing at all? If not, do you even need to include it on your CV?

Comment: Yes, both jobs are nursing jobs, so it's tough to leave off the resume.